# Array_accum returning null values in postgres SQL when we have 350 rows in a table

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.2

I am using following query

```
select distinct throttle_id, array_accum(param) over (partition by throttle_id) as script_exclude from throttle_data where exclude = 't' and valve_type = 513 and throttle_id = 1270571881
```

and I'm getting null value in `script_exclude` field

Sample values I have in param column is,

> airfare/pricing/launch_0tc.wql airfare/pricing/launch_0xp.wql airfare/pricing/launch_0xp_down.wql airfare/pricing/launch_0xp_up.wql

No.of rows is `351`.

Please advice how could I get these all value.

Regards,
Sachin Jain

Comment: What does `array_accum()` do? It's not a standard Postgres function. If you want a comma separated list then why don't you use `string_agg()`. Also: the way you use `distinct` together with a window functions seems to indicate that you actually want `group by` with a regular aggregate

Answer (score 0):

Try the following instead:

```
select throttle_id, array_agg(param) as script_exclude 
  from throttle_data where exclude = 't' 
       and valve_type = 513 and throttle_id = 1270571881
group by throttle_id;
```

If that still returns null then try:

```
select * from throttle_data
 WHERE exclude = 't'
       and valve_type = 513 and throttle_id = 1270571881;
```

To see what is actually aggregated.

If that doesn't return any rows, then something is wrong with your criteria in your where clause.